# Image href not working (CSS and HTML)

Tags: html, css

I haven't dabbled in html or css in a long time so please be gentle.

I'm trying to create a button which links to a website and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm guessing it may be how I'm nesting it but I'm not too sure. I've spent about half a day google-ing potential issues and I've tried what I can so I'm turning to the community for help.

Edit:
I've narrowed down the HTML to the problem area so it doesn't confuse everyone. I've tried 4 different ways to make the links and I can't click on any of them (they don't behave as links so I can't debug them).

**HEAD/CSS:**

```
<head>
  <style>
     body {
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size:12px;
     display:block;
     margin:0;
     Padding:0;
     background-color:lightslategrey;
     }
     a {
     color:white;
     text-decoration:none;
     }
     /* div {
     display: block;
     } 
     span {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     line-height: normal;      
     } */
     ul {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     }
     .toolbar {
     position: fixed;
     display: inline-block;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     /*height:36px;*/
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
     font-size: 100%;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 5px;
     z-index:100;
     }
     .menu-btn {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 100%;
     left: 50px;
     right: 20px;
     /*background-color: cyan;*/
     }
     .menu-btn img {
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align:middle;
     }
     .bannerpic {
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     position: relative;
     top:25px;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     vertical-align: middle;
     background-color: grey;
     background-image:url("banner.jpg");
     background-position:center;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width:100%;
     height:450px;
     box-shadow: 0 0 65px #000000;
     z-index:-1;
     }
     .bannercontainer {
     position: absolute;
     margin:auto;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     bottom:0;
     /*padding:5px;*/
     display: block;
     top:0px;
     /*background-color: orange;*/
     background-color: black;
     background: rgb(0,0,0);
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
     width: 900px;
     height: 350px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     }
     .bannertextbox {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     margin: auto;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     padding: 40px;
     width:80%;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     /*background-color: pink;
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000000;*/
     }
     .bannertitle {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     /*background-color:aqua;*/
     padding:10px;
     font-size: 400%;
     /*bottom:0;*/
     }
     .bannersubtitle {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     padding:10px;
     font-size: 150%;
     /*text-transform: uppercase;
     bottom:0;*/
     /*background-color:blue;*/
     }
     .qt {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     padding:1px;
     /*background-color:purple;*/
     }
     .qt-btn {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 15px;
     /*background-color:red;*/
     }
     .qt-btn-txt {
     padding-top: 10px;
     font-size:90%; 
     /*background-color:green;*/
     }
     .content {
     position: relative;
     margin:auto;
     padding:auto;
     width:1200px;
     height:2000px;
     color: black;
     font-size: 100%;
     background-color:white;
     text-align:left;
     }
     .mytext {
     padding:20px;
     text-align:justify;
     }
     ul#nav li{
     display:inline;
     /*font-color:red;*/
     padding:10px;
     }
     ul#tasks li{
     display:inline;
     /*font-color:red;*/
     }
  </style>
```

**BODY/HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="bannerpic">
     <div class="bannercontainer">
        <div class="bannertextbox">
           <div class="bannertitle">
              This is the Main Banner
           </div>
           <div class="bannersubtitle">
              QT Links
           </div>
           <div class="qt">
              <ul id="tasks">
                 <li>
                    <div class="qt-btn">
                       <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                       <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-folder-128.png" alt="img1" style="width:72px;height:72px;">
                       </a>
                       <div class="qt-btn-txt">
                          QT1
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <div class="qt-btn">
                       <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-folder-128.png" alt="img2" style="width:72px;height:72px;">
                       <div class="qt-btn-txt">
                          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                          QT2
                          </a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <div class="qt-btn">
                       <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                          <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-folder-128.png" alt="img3" style="width:72px;height:72px;">
                          <div class="qt-btn-txt">
                             QT2
                          </div>
                       </a>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                       <div class="qt-btn">
                          <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-folder-128.png" alt="img4" style="width:72px;height:72px;">
                          <div class="qt-btn-txt">
                             QT2
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </a>
                 <li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <div class="mytext">
        This is some text.
     </div>
  </div>
```

I've commented the places I have issues with. I have no problems with the links in the nav, it's just the banner.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the console, any errors? specifically `404 Not Found` ?

Comment: Are all of your images in the same directory as the HTML document?

Comment: If you have no errors with your image or get any 404 errors, have you tried using `https` instead of `http` on your `href`?

Comment: it doesn't behave as a link. It's as if it's a static image.

Comment: So I've tried to shuffle around the coding and it still doesn't seem to work. I can't get them to behave as links. They're still static images that I can't click on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the z-index: -1 you have on the bannerpic. This makes the body overlap the content of bannerpic. :-) Try removing that one line.

```
.bannerpic {
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     position: relative;
     top:25px;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     vertical-align: middle;
     background-color: grey;
     background-image:url("banner.jpg");
     background-position:center;
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width:100%;
     height:450px;
     box-shadow: 0 0 65px #000000;
     /* z-index:-1; <-- This */
}
```

Comment: Wow. So simple yet so effective. Thanks!!

Comment: It can be very hard to spot some error, like this one. But my spider sense was tingling ;-) Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have forgotten to add a link tag to options 1 and 2.
The tag `<a>` needs to have the text and image inside it.

```
 <li>
       <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
          option2
          <img class="da" src="da.png" width="10px" height="5px">
        </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Sorry, I purposely took the links out as they weren't the main focus. The main focus is where the comments are in the banner, not the nav. Sorry for the confusion.